# Llama_index One of nodes or index_struct must be provided

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, llama-index

I am getting the same error every time. I have tried a lot of solutions but i cant get it to work.

I am using the new version of llama_index v=0.6.35 i believe.

I always get the following error:

**

> Error: One of nodes or index_struct must be provided.

**

```
from llama_index.indices.loading import load_index_from_storage
from llama_index import (
    GPTVectorStoreIndex,
    SimpleDirectoryReader,
    LLMPredictor,
    ServiceContext,
    StorageContext,
    VectorStoreIndex,
)
from langchain import OpenAI
import gradio as gr
import os
import openai
import json

os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "--APIKEY--"
openai.api_key = "--APIKEY--"


def construct_index(directory_path):
    num_outputs = 512

    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(
        llm=OpenAI(
            temperature=0.7, model_name="text-davinci-003", max_tokens=num_outputs
        )
    )

    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor)

    docs = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path).load_data()

    index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(docs, service_context=service_context)

    index.storage_context.persist(persist_dir="index")

    return index


def chatbot(input_text):
    print(input_text)
    storage_context = StorageContext(
        vector_store="index/vector_store.json",
        index_store="index/index_store.json",
        graph_store="index/graph_store.json",
        docstore="index/docstore.json",
    )
    print("I have passed the storage_context")

    try:
        index = GPTVectorStoreIndex(storage_context=storage_context)
        index.load()
        print("I have passed the index")
        response = index.query(input_text, response_mode="compact")
        return response.response
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return None


iface = gr.Interface(
    fn=chatbot,
    inputs=gr.inputs.Textbox(lines=7, label="Enter your text"),
    outputs=gr.outputs.Textbox(label="Response"),
    title="Custom-trained AI Chatbot",
)

index = construct_index("docs")
iface.launch(share=False)
```

I am not able to resolve this. I have seen a lot of post only talking about it.

This is the first time i am doing a project like this one:

I got the tutorial from this post:
https://medium.com/@sohaibshaheen/train-chatgpt-with-custom-data-and-create-your-own-chat-bot-using-macos-fb78c2f9646d

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the try block I see you have passed the `storage_context` directly to `GPTVectorStoreIndex` constructor which will lead to this error, instead you have to pass it to the method called `from_documents` of the `GPTVectorStoreIndex` object as below.

```
GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(storage_context=context)
```